# All objects overwritten by addObject: when using NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsxmlparser

I have created an `NSMutableArray` called `tempArray` which holds the characters for the three elements I want. Currently, when I set a breakpoint and let the parser run, `tempArray` correctly changes each time, and gives me the information I need (latitude, longitude, the-name).

Then, when the parser calls the `didEndElement...` method for "a-location", I add `tempArray` to the main `NSMutableArray` named `parsedNearMe`, which should hold all of the a-locations(each has the-name, latitude, longitude).

This all works as expected.

**The Problem:**
Each time I add `tempArray` to `parsedNearMe`, it adds the new object, but sets all of the existing objects to the values of the new object.

**What I think is the problem**
I think that the problem is that since I am setting the current elements to `tempArray`, and each time I'm overwriting every object in `parsedNearMe` because every object is a pointer to the same `tempArray`.

**Possible solutions I've attempted or researched with no luck**
-Somehow clear the pointer so I can reuse `tempArray` (or reinitialize it?)
-dynamically create a new name in place of `tempArray` each time (don't think is possible in Objective-C)

I appreciate any suggestions, as I have spent so many hours on this already I am doing circles. Also, I would kind of like the current architecture to work(getting one large array of arrays, so I can call 1 of the arrays and get all of the data I need for that annotation).

My code is as follows:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"a-location"]) 
    {
        if (!tempArray)
            tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        return;
    }


    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"latitude"] ) 
    {
        latitude = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        return;
    } 


    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"longitude"] ) {
        longitude = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        return;
    }


    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"the-name"] ) {
        myName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        return;
    }

}



-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    [currentString appendString:string];

}



- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"latitude"] ) {
        [tempArray addObject:currentString];
        return;
    }

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"longitude"] ) {
        [tempArray addObject:currentString];
        return;
    }

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"the-name"] ) {
        [tempArray addObject:currentString];
        return; 
    }

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"a-location"])
    {
        [parsedNearMe setObject:tempArray forKey:[NSDate date]];
        [tempArray removeAllObjects];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

1. The `didEndElement` for `a-location` sets the value keyed by the date, but then takes the pointer that points to that same object and removes all the items that were in that object. So, instead of:

   ```
   if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"a-location"])
   {
       [parsedNearMe setObject:tempArray forKey:[NSDate date]];
       [tempArray removeAllObjects];
   }
   ```

   You might replace that with:

   ```
   if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"a-location"])
   {
       [parsedNearMe setObject:tempArray forKey:[NSDate date]];
       tempArray = nil;  // make sure you don't touch that object you just added to parsedNearMe
   }
   ```
2. I doubt this particular XML will suffer from this problem, but your `foundCharacters` assumes that a single call will return all of the data. That's not a valid assumption. Sometimes it takes multiple calls.
3. You're also having `foundCharacters` append strings for portions of the XML for which you have no interest. You should make sure that `currentString` is `nil` except when parsing latitude, longitude, and name.

So, at the very least, I'd suggest something like the following:

```
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    parsedNearMe = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
    currentString = nil;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"a-location"]) 
    {
        tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"latitude"] || 
             [elementName isEqualToString:@"longitude"] || 
             [elementName isEqualToString:@"the-name"]) 
    {
        currentString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [currentString appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"latitude"] ||
        [elementName isEqualToString:@"longitude"] ||
        [elementName isEqualToString:@"the-name"] )
    {
        [tempArray addObject:currentString];
        currentString = nil;
    }
    else if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"a-location"])
    {
        [parsedNearMe setObject:tempArray forKey:[NSDate date]];
        tempArray = nil;
    }
}
```

This mirrors your current logic, creating dictionary keyed by some random timestamp, and the value for each dictionary item is an array of latitude, longitude, and name.

Personally, I think this design suffers from two additional flaws, though:

1. You're keying your dictionary by some random object, `[NSDate date]`. That offers no value. You might as well make this an array.
2. Your array of latitude, longitude, and the-name is ambiguous. Your data structure is highly contingent upon the order of items in the XML file. If you're going to use a dictionary for anything, I'd use it here.

So, bottom line, rather than a dictionary whose values are arrays, I'd flip that around. I'd suggest an array of dictionary objects. I think the `parsedNearMe` should be a `NSMutableArray`. And instead of a `NSMutableArray` called `tempArray`, you should use a `NSMutableDictionary` called `tempDictionary`:

First, define a few ivars:

```
NSMutableArray *parsedNearMe;         // this was a NSMutableDictionary
NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary;
```

And then your `NSXMLParserDelegate` routines might look like:

```
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    parsedNearMe = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
    currentString = nil;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"a-location"]) 
    {
        tempDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"latitude"] || 
             [elementName isEqualToString:@"longitude"] || 
             [elementName isEqualToString:@"the-name"]) 
    {
        currentString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [currentString appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"latitude"] ||
        [elementName isEqualToString:@"longitude"] ||
        [elementName isEqualToString:@"the-name"] )
    {
        [tempDictionary setObject:currentString forKey:elementName];
        currentString = nil;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"a-location"])
    {
        [parsedNearMe addObject:tempDictionary];
        tempDictionary = nil;
    }
}
```

Or, if you'd like to store latitude and longitude as `NSNumber` objects instead as strings, you could replace the `didEndElement` with:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"latitude"] ||
        [elementName isEqualToString:@"longitude"])
    {
        [tempDictionary setObject:@([currentString doubleValue]) forKey:elementName];
        currentString = nil;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"the-name"] )
    {
        [tempDictionary setObject:currentString forKey:elementName];
        currentString = nil;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"a-location"])
    {
        [parsedNearMe addObject:tempDictionary];
        tempDictionary = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very well structured answer, thank you.

Although I haven't tried your solution yet, I believe this will solve my issue: tempArray = nil; 

I also agree with your design suggestions. 

Actually, I originally had it as just two NSMutableArrays, but ended up with the current dictionary design because I was just trying many ways and thought maybe using an NSDictionary with a key would solve the issue of overwriting the objects every time.

Comment: Also, that's also why I was trying to put a random date as they key. For some reason I thought giving it a unique name(the date) would stop the objects from being overwritten. I also tried starting a counter at 0, and using the number as a key. Thanks for clearing this up :).